# Can i retain old value of scope and update some other value to other div in AngualrJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Well,I'll try to explain my approach why I am doing this. I have trimmed the code for the sake of simplicity. I want to create one div where there should be `<h4>BroadCategory Name</h4>` and below this headline, I am calling one API to fetch some images associated with that **BroadCategory Name**

```
  <div ng-controller="NavigationController">
     <div ng-repeat="primaryItems in categories">
        <div>
          <h4><span>{{primaryItems.BroadCategory}}</span></h4>
        </div>

        <div ng-init="getImgForCategory(this.primaryItems)">
           <div ng-repeat="ad in ads">
             {{ ad.ad_type }}
             <a ng-href="#productList/{{primaryItems.BroadCategory}}">
               <img src="{{ ad.images[0] }}" >
             </a>
           </div>
        </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

My Controller:

```
$http.get("/get_categories/")
    .success(function(response){
        $scope.categories = response;
    })
    .error(function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    });


$scope.getImgForCategory = function (categoryInfo) {
    var category = (categoryInfo.BroadCategory);
    $http.get('/Some_API_ad_type='+category)  //API to fetch some images associated with that **BroadCategory**
        .success(function (response) {
            $scope.ads = response;
        })
        .error(function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        })
}
```

**Issue** : Issue is that `$scope.ads` keeps the value of last called API response and so the  `{{ ad.ad_type }}` and similar ads attributes have all the same values (which is the response for the last BroadCategory name)

How can I resolve this with best Angular approach?

```html
<h1>Expected Output: </h1>
<h4>BroadCategory1</h4>
BC1_data1
<br>BC1_data2


<h4>BroadCategory2</h4>
BC2_data1
<br>BC2_data2

<h1>Actual Output: </h1>
<h4>BroadCategory1</h4>
BC2_data1
<br>BC2_data2

<h4>BroadCategory1</h4>
BC2_data1
<br>BC2_data2
```

Comment: Consider putting this data inside directives with isolate scope, instead of setting it on the scope of a shared controller.

Comment: @DanielBeck: Cool. Will keep this in mind

Comment: For this particular case the answer you've accepted may be more appropriate, but, yeah, isolate scope is the general solution to "data in directive A is getting clobbered by data from directive B"

Comment: Yep. M trying to learn angular, so best approach is always there to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the generated html in your inner ng-repeat all use the same $scope.ads list. So if that gets updated, all data on your screen will just show the new value of $scope.ads.

What I would do is link the adds to the category. Like the following:

```
$scope.getImgForCategory = function (categoryInfo) {
    var category = (categoryInfo.BroadCategory);
    $http.get('/Some_API_ad_type='+category)
        .success(function (response) {
            categoryInfo.ads = response;
        })
        .error(function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        })
}
```

.

```
<div ng-controller="NavigationController">
 <div ng-repeat="primaryItems in categories">
    <div>
      <h4><span>{{primaryItems.BroadCategory}}</span></h4>
    </div>

    <div ng-init="getImgForCategory(primaryItems)">
       <div ng-repeat="ad in primaryItems.ads">
         {{ ad.ad_type }}
         <a ng-href="#productList/{{primaryItems.BroadCategory}}">
           <img src="{{ ad.images[0] }}" >
         </a>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: So you save the "previous" api responses where they belong, namely within a category.

Comment: That was really smart approach , Thanks :)